# If a certain API doesn't allow to get multiple places in 1 GET request, is foreach-ing and making 1 GET request per place the only option?

Tags: php, laravel

In the function below I firstly get all the places the user has wishlisted. Every place has a property called `place_id` which must be used in the GET request to Google places API. This is why I loop through all places, make a GET request for each one and then push the result in an array which is finally sent to the front-end.

The problem I see with this is that if I've wishlisted too many places, this function will take a long time to execute since it'll have to execute 5-10-100 GET requests. Is this the correct way of doing this? Are there any alternatives?

```
public function getWishlist($username){
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    $wishlistedPlaces = $user->wishlistedPlaces;
    $finalPlaces = [];

    foreach ($wishlistedPlaces as $wishlistedPlace) {
        $get = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" . $wishlistedPlace->place_id . "&key=");
        $result = json_decode($get);
        array_push($finalPlaces, $result);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'wishlistedPlaces' => $finalPlaces,
    ], 201);
}
```

Comment: Well . One option is you can send the wish list and loop it  in the client side

Comment: I have to get the places' information by making the GET requests in the back-end first though. So I can not avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply return the list of Place Ids to the client and then make the API calls in JavaScript?

Or, if you need to do some PHP processing of the detail data, what about calling your `getWishlist` method via Ajax. Maybe add the ability to return data in chunks (maybe every 5 or 10 places). This way, you could display a nice message to the user to let them know the data is loading.